# Parsing values for an array in Json file with c# using lambda expressions

Tags: c#, json, rest, api, asp.net-core

I have this .Json file:

```
[
    {
        "targets":[
            "192.168.1.101:9182",
            "192.168.1.103:9100",
            "192.168.1.105:9182"  
        ]
    }
]
```

I want to parse the targets and them by value. 
I have already did a function that parse the Json file and log out result:
The class model is:

```
public class targetResponse
    {
        public IList<string> targets { get; set; }
    }
```

in my Controller I have this function that log out all the value:

```
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IEnumerable<targetResponse>> Get()
        {
            IList<targetResponse> myList = new List<targetResponse>();
            var jsonString = System.IO.File
               .ReadAllText(@"D:\\Paths\\targets.json");
            myList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<targetResponse>>(jsonString);

            return myList;
        }
```

[image]

The function I want to create is that I want to get only one value from that Json file, I have tried to do as following but it doesnt work:

```
    [HttpGet("{string}")]
    public async Task<dynamic> Get(string _string)
    {
        IList<targetResponse> myList = new List<targetResponse>();
        var jsonString = System.IO.File
           .ReadAllText(@"D:\\Paths\\targets.json");
        myList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<targetResponse>>(jsonString);
        return myList.FirstOrDefault().targets.Select(r=>r.ToString()==_string);
    }
```

[image]

I also want to create an Update/Create/Delete methods (CRUD) if there is any tutorial of how to please share thanks

Comment: What doesn't work exactly? Have you tried to compile your code?

Comment: I don't get the value, I'll post screens

Comment: I have added 2 screenshots :)

Comment: you get a list of ``bool`` here : ``Select(r=>r.ToString()==_string)``, change it by ``where`` for example. use @Pavel Anikhousk response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an incorrect `Linq` statement in `Get` method. Instead of

```cs
myList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<targetResponse>>(jsonString);
return myList.FirstOrDefault().targets.Select(r=>r.ToString()==_string);
```

You can write

```cs
myList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<targetResponse>>(jsonString);
return myList.FirstOrDefault().targets.FirstOrDefault(r => r == _string);
```

Use `Where` or `FirstOrDefault` instead of `Select`, otherwise you are getting a list of booleans. There is also no need to use `ToString()`, because `targets` is already list of strings

Comment: Okeym I have tried both, but when I tried to go to the link: [link](https://localhost:9898/api/target/192.168.1.101:9182) it doesnt redirect, when I do the debug I find that the return will return the 3 string(i.e: `"192.168.1.101:9182","192.168.1.103:9100","192.168.1.105:9182"`)